# Different-sized Tiles in Windows App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I know that I can use the ListView and GridView to create "Tiles"/Items whatever size I want, but how can I create different-sized Tiles for use within my app? This will need to work with a ListView or GridView.

I have tried so many things but I just have absolutely no idea how to do this. Any help will be much appreciated.

In case I haven't described what I am trying to achieve properly, here is a pic:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to create a new class inheriting from GridView and override the PrepareContainerForItemOverride method. In which you can set the Column Span and RowSpan to Child item based on the model data. Consider your model class contains the Spanning information.

```
public class VariableGrid : GridView
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        ITileItem tile = item as ITileItem;
        if (tile != null)
        {
            GridViewItem griditem = element as GridViewItem;
            if (griditem != null)
            {
                VariableSizedWrapGrid.SetColumnSpan(griditem, tile.ColumnSpan);
                VariableSizedWrapGrid.SetRowSpan(griditem, tile.RowSpan);
            }
        }
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    }
}
```

More information : http://wpfplayground.blogspot.in/2013/03/different-sized-tile-items-in-winrt.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `ItemsPanel`/`ItemsPanelTemplate` of your list to `VariableSizedWrapGrid` and set `Grid.RowSpan`/`ColumnSpan` of your list items to the values you want. I believe you can do that in `ItemContainerStyle` of the list control, which is best extracted by right-clicking the control in VS XAML design view or in Blend and selecting "Edit Additional Templates"/"Edit Generated Item Container".